# Stopping android logcat that is executing in a child process

Tags: android, ruby, process, android-logcat, kill-process

I am writing a ruby script in which I want to execute the android logcat -v time command in a child process and after some time kill the process (when the the parent is done doing xyz).

For example I have:
childpid = Process.fork { 
        `adb -s <device-serial> logcat -c`
        `adb -s  <device-serial> logcat -v time>/path-to-file/forkLog.log`
    }

```
sleep(30)
    #parent do thing else here ...
Process.kill("SIGHUP", childpid)  #kill the child process
```

---

According to what I've read the adb logcat code is executed in another child sup-process, so when I try to do a Process.kill the childpid stops but its sub-process does not.

how do I kill the logcat -v time>forklog.log process from the parent process??

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when you're using fork to call a bash script, you'll want to use [Kernel::exec()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) instead of Kernel::system() or Kernel::`

```
Process.fork{exec('adb -s <device-serial> logcat -c && adb -s  <device-serial> logcat -v time>/path-to-file/forkLog.log'}
```

The difference is that exec will *replace* the Ruby process with the shell script, while the other two will create a subprocess.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it does not seem to work adb might be running in another subprocess--- after I did some further reading

Comment: basically I need a way to kill all (great)grandchildren and then kill child in order for this to work... but how to do this?